# how to get how many sattelites in view android 2.1 sdk

Tags: android

how to get count of satellites in Android 2.1 when ever am using loction.getExtras().getInt("satellites"); my app automatically closed please any one help me how to resolve it.
And one more thing in android 1.5 its working fine .....

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this working in your case?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER

If the app just closes it would be nice if you can post the exception so that we can help you.

Comment: i resolved the problem for getting Satellites am using GpsSatellite class getstatus() method so its working fine